# unit test for inputParser output matlab

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, sanitization

I am just beginning to dive into testing in Matlab, and I am trying to write a test which will check whether inputParser is properly catching incorrect function argument values. For example:

```
function [imageNamesForImport] = imageFileSearch(fileList, stringToMatch)

iP = inputParser;
iP.addRequired('fileList', @isstruct);
iP.addRequired('stringToMatch', @ischar);
iP.parse(fileList, stringToMatch);
```

will throw an error if I pass a variable as fileList which is not a structure

```
fileList = 'foo'
stringToMatch = 'bar'
imageNamesForImport = imageFileSearch(fileList, stringToMatch)

Error using imageFileSearch (line 7)
The value of 'fileList' is invalid. It must satisfy the function: isstruct.
```

Is it possible to write a unit test to check for this output without having to use a series of try / catch statements to assign custom errors for verifyError?

Comment: What do you mean by "without having to use a series of try / catch statements to assign custom errors for verifyError?"

Are you trying to use verifyError but don't care about the error ids because they can change? How would you use try/catch in conjunction with verifyError? To me is seems the two would never meet (the try-catch is inside the verifyError).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up your own unit testing framework and use a single `try-catch` block inside of a `for` loop:

```
% Set up test cases
test(1).fileList = 'foo';
test(2).fileList.a = 12;
test(3).fileList.a = 'bar';

test(1).stringToMatch = 'bar';
test(2).stringToMatch = 5;
test(3).stringToMatch = 'bar';

% Run tests
myerrs = [];
for ii = 1:length(test)
    try
        imageNamesForImport = imageFileSearch(test(ii).fileList, test(ii).stringToMatch);
    catch err
        myerrs = [myerrs err];
        % Any other custom things here
    end
end
```

Which in this case gives us a 1x2 structure of errors that we can investigate.

---

You could also utilize [MATLAB's Unit Testing Framework](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-unit-test-framework.html). Here's a simple example for a [Script-Based Unit Test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-script-based-unit-tests.html):

**imageFileSearch.m**

```
function [imageNamesForImport] = imageFileSearch(fileList, stringToMatch)

iP = inputParser;
iP.addRequired('fileList', @isstruct);
iP.addRequired('stringToMatch', @ischar);
iP.parse(fileList, stringToMatch);
imageNamesForImport = 'hi';
```

**testtrial.m**

```
%% Test 1
fileList = 'foo';
stringToMatch = 'bar';
imageNamesForImport = imageFileSearch(fileList, stringToMatch);

%% Test 2
fileList.a = 12;
stringToMatch = 5;
imageNamesForImport = imageFileSearch(fileList, stringToMatch);

%% Test 3
fileList.a = 'bar';
stringToMatch = 'bar';
imageNamesForImport = imageFileSearch(fileList, stringToMatch);
```

Which gives us the following command window output:

```
Running testtrial

================================================================================
Error occurred in testtrial/Test1 and it did not run to completion.

    --------------
    Error Details:
    --------------
    The value of 'fileList' is invalid. It must satisfy the function: isstruct.

================================================================================
.
================================================================================
Error occurred in testtrial/Test2 and it did not run to completion.

    --------------
    Error Details:
    --------------
    The value of 'stringToMatch' is invalid. It must satisfy the function: ischar.

================================================================================
..
Done testtrial
__________

Failure Summary:

     Name             Failed  Incomplete  Reason(s)
    ================================================
     testtrial/Test1    X         X       Errored.
    ------------------------------------------------
     testtrial/Test2    X         X       Errored.
```

Answer (score 1):

See my clarifying question if this does not answer your question, but you should just be able to use verifyError with the inputParser specific ID:

```
fileList = 'foo'
stringToMatch = 'bar'
testCase.verifyError(@() imageFileSearch(fileList, stringToMatch), ...
    'MATLAB:InputParser:ArgumentFailedValidation');
```

If you want to validate a more specific error happened you can instead validate with a function that throws your own message and id:

```
function [imageNamesForImport] = imageFileSearch(fileList, stringToMatch)

iP = inputParser;
iP.addRequired('fileList', @validateStruct);
iP.addRequired('stringToMatch', @ischar);
iP.parse(fileList, stringToMatch);


function validateStruct(s)
assert(isstruct(s), 'ImageFileSearch:IncorrectInput:FileListMustBeStruct', ...
    'fileList must be a struct.'); % Can also just be inlined in addRequired call
```

Then you can test it with:

```
fileList = 'foo'
stringToMatch = 'bar'
testCase.verifyError(@() imageFileSearch(fileList, stringToMatch), ...
    'ImageFileSearch:IncorrectInput:FileListMustBeStruct');
```